# R Plotly with Dropdown Menu

Tags: r, menu, dropdown, plotly

How can I use plotly to build a plot with dropdown menus for a line plot (not for a map like the below)? A simple example would be great like the rChart below.

Plot with dropdown menus (controls) using rCharts:
http://bl.ocks.org/ramnathv/raw/8475226/

The only example I found using plotly with dropdown (for a map but I would like for a line plot):
https://plot.ly/r/dropdowns/

Thank you.

Comment: Your second link IS an example. What do you want more?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the request for a line map using plotly, not for a map like the site has as an example.